# How can I commit/push my Android Studio project to another GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

I'm currently building an app with one of my coworkers and we came across a problem.

We already have one GitHub repository where everything is committed. But we wanted to create another repository so we can change the code etc. without damaging the original.

We added the new remote to the project and have removed the old one but now, when we try to commit, it still wants to commit to the original.

How do we change that?

Comment: The whole point of git is to be able to change the code etc. without damaging the original. Committing and then pushing to the existing repo does not damage anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the set-upstream command to connect your local branch to a new branch in the origin:

```
git push --set-upstream <remote> <branch>
```

I am not shure if this will also work with a branch that is part of another repository though.

Anyway you dont need a new repository I think. What you are describing can be done by creating a new branch on your repo. Often you will find projects organized like this:

- master-branch: this is there the official/ release version of your code lives
- development-branches: here you and your colleges can add new features and test them without affecting the master branch or other development branches.

When you are done with a new feature, you can create merge-requests to add it to the master branch. You should have a look at git workflows to understand how to work with git:
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The `commit` itself happens on your local machine, it continues to do so after adding a 2nd remote or replacing the 1st remote. It's the `push` command that you are looking for, I believe.

You can push to your specific remote with a command like:
`git push <remote> <refspec>`
Where `remote` is typically (but not always) `origin`. If in doubt you can find the name with the `git remote` command.
The `refspec` can be left empty to push all new commits on branches that are already on your remote, or set to a specific branch or several other values of what you'd like to push.

Note that in your case, assuming the new remote does not have your branch yet, it is crucial to set `refspec` for your first push. Check [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) of the `git push` command for a more complete explanation of how to use these options.